# What the difference between Java8 Collectors and Collector?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

What is the difference between `Collectors` & `Collector`. I know that one is interface & one is class. I want to know with example what is the actual difference and When to use which one with real time example.
Hi all I already mentioned in my question I know the basic difference and I gone through the documentation also, **I just want to know the purpose to introduce this two thing with example and When should use which one?**

Comment: Try reading the documentation, i.e. read the javadoc of them both. Then you'll see the difference. Just the first paragraph of each of them should be quiet eye-opening. --- [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html): *A mutable reduction operation* --- [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html): *Implementations of `Collector`*

Comment: Hi all I already mentioned in my question I kNow the basic difference and I gone through the document also, I just want to know the purpose to introduce this two thing with example

Comment: The javadoc of `Collectors` already show you examples of use. What more do you need? You can write your own implementation of the `Collector` interface, if you choose, or you can use one of the standard implementations provided by `Collectors`. If you don't understand, in general, what the "actual difference" (as you called it) is between an interface and factory class providing implementations of the interface, then you should read up on *interfaces*, *implementations*, and what a [*factory method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is.

Answer (score 3):

`Collectors` is just a class with static methods which create commonly used `Collector`s.